# Placing PDF in appendix section places it on a whole new page

Tags: appendices, pdfpages

I'm currently using the LaTeX code for putting pdf files in my appendix:

```
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

...

\begin{appendices}
    \include{chapters/appendix}
\end{appendices}

...

\chapter{Appendix 1}

\section{Item one}
\includepdf[pages=-]{docs/pdf_doc_1.pdf}
```

Which makes this happen:

[image]

Is there any way to stop it from breaking or even make it look nicer?

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for `includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Comment: @Johannes_B how would I use graphix with my pdf files?

Comment: Just as with a normal `jpg` file. You are using a package that is designed to include pdf files as whole pages, which is not what you want. You want to use `\includegraphics`. Whoever told you `pdfpages` is the right tool lied to you.

Comment: *"Using pdflatex several graphics formats are supported: pdf, png and jpg."* from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Importing_external_graphics

Comment: @Johannes_B are there any options I should look at using? Because when I use include graphics, it keeps the header and file on same page but it doesn't span pages!

Comment: Just use it like you are used to with `jpg` or `png` files. There is no differnce.

Comment: @Johannes_B see my updated comment

Comment: @Johannes_B because `page=...` is for a singular page

Comment: You could add the first page with includegraphics and the rest with includepdf.

Comment: @Johannes_B is there a short hand for pages aside from the first in `pdfpages`?

Comment: can you not just input the tex source so it fits the natural styling and layout of the new document? Do you have to include the pdf? (ignore me if the included pdf isn't tex generated:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah the PDF is not tex generated :)

Comment: in that case as Johannes commented you could include each page separately via \includegraphics rather than use the pdfpages route